# Program in C that reads binary file and outputs only zeros in float notation instead of file contents

Tags: c

I am not that comfortable with the C language or really writing code. I am trying to read a file in binary and output it to the screen. I am using fread and fopen since these work well with binary. I have this code that compiles but when i run my code as ./a.out data1 i only get 0.0000. The file contents are 4, 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4. This is what is supposed to be outputted. 1.1000 2.2000 3.3000 4.40000 only the floats. I supspect the problem is that im not passing the values in the file to the array correctly. I would appreciate any help or comments. My code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *ifile;
    int cnt, i;
    float *fptr;
    fptr = malloc (cnt * sizeof (float));
    ifile = fopen (argv[1], "rb");
    fread (fptr, sizeof (float), cnt, ifile);
    printf ("%f\n", *fptr);
}

// new code that works
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *ifile;
    int cnt, i;
    float *fptr;
    ifile = fopen (argv[1], "rb");
    if (fread (&cnt, sizeof (int), 1, ifile) != 1) {
        printf ("%d\n", cnt);
    }
    fptr = malloc (cnt * sizeof (float));
    fread (fptr, sizeof (float), cnt, ifile);
    for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
        printf ("%f\n", *fptr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: a. `fptr= malloc(cnt*sizeof(float));` and `fread(fptr, sizeof(float), cnt, ifile);` ... the value of `cnt` is ? b. No check that the file opened successfully.

Comment: Im trying to dynamically create an array of floats using the first number of the file with the malloc function. I am not sure if i did it correctly.

Comment: `cnt` is never assigned anywhere but is used in malloc() and fread(), thus running the program in your question leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: how do you know the content of the file? did you print it? You are reading it as binary, is it really binary or an ascii file?

Comment: This is for an assignment, the values where given to us but i can't really see the file. I am now adding another fread statement for  "cnt" to see if this fixes the problem.

Comment: Note that your code only prints a single value, effectively `fptr[0]`, and it's possible that value could be zero.  You should be printing `cnt` different values, once you've read a value into `cnt`.

Comment: Alright thank you. Im trying to print the floats and use the int of the file as a way to know how many floats there are. Then create an array of type float with the size being equal to the integer. Not really the int but the value 4. so an array of 4 floats.

Comment: Thank you. cnt was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't set `cnt` anywhere so you read an unspecified number of floats which may or may not be correct.  If I hard code it to `4` and use a binary data file with 4 floats in it, it works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE *ifile;
    int cnt = 4, i;
    float *fptr;
    fptr= malloc(cnt*sizeof(float));
    ifile=fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    fread(fptr, sizeof(float), cnt, ifile);
    printf("%f\n", *fptr);
    printf("%f\n", fptr[1]);
    printf("%f\n", fptr[2]);
    printf("%f\n", fptr[3]);
}
```

running the program:

```
$ ./test-prog data
1.100000
2.200000
3.300000
4.400000
$ hd data
00000000  cd cc 8c 3f cd cc 0c 40  33 33 53 40 cd cc 8c 40  |...?...@33S@...@|
00000010
```